# How do I add a forgot username button/link to web2py login form?

Tags: authentication, web2py

The default login form has a "Lost Password" button:

[image]

How do I add a "Forgot Username" button or link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Register" and "Lost Password" buttons are added to the form in the `/views/default/user.html` view template, so you can edit that template to add the additional button. After:

```
if request.args(0)=='login':
    if not 'register' in auth.settings.actions_disabled:
        form.add_button(T('Register'),URL(args='register', vars={'_next': request.vars._next} if request.vars._next else None),_class='btn')
    pass
    if not 'request_reset_password' in auth.settings.actions_disabled:
        form.add_button(T('Lost Password'),URL(args='request_reset_password'),_class='btn')
    pass
```

add:

```
    form.add_button(T('Forgot Username'), URL(args='retrieve_username'),
                    _class='btn')
```